# undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a module in ruby and whenever i use a comparison operator i get the above error. none of the operators work.

```
if self.health >= opponent.health
        [:attack, opponent]
    else
        [:rest]
    end
```

Please let me know if I'm doing some kind of a mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you really sure `self.health` is not `nil`? Because that's what the error message claims... (Maybe a typo somewhere in your code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>=` can be used only with Comparable objects. Your error message indicates that `self.health` is `nil`. You need to have a Comparable object for both `self.health` and `opponent.health`, and further have comparison defined between them.

Comment: `Comparable` implements `>=` - not `Enumerable`. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Comparable.html

Comment: Not quite. The method `>=` can be added to any class and is used in case of comparison. Besides, the error text contains the class of the object that does not contain the requested method, `NilClass` in this case, which can be reasonably expected to be incomparable. ;)

Comment: @user1252434 As you say, you can define it on any class, but I assumed the OP will not go as far to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As @sawa said, the reason you're comparison is raising an exception is that `self.health` is `nil`, for which the method `>=` is not defined (though as mentioned by @user1252434, the `Comparable` explanation isn't quite correct. The method `>=` can be defined in any class, with or without the module `Comparable`). Depending on what you're comparing, it might be easy to use default values for this type of comparison. For `String` objects, you can call `to_s` to use `""` (the empty string) as a default for your comparisons:

```
self.health.to_s >= opponent.health.to_s
#Compares "" >= "" if the attributes are nil
```

For Fixnum objects (integers), you can use `to_i` to use `0` as the default:

```
self.health.to_i >= opponent.health.to_i
#Compares 0 >= 0 if the attributes are nil
```

And for Float objects, you can use `to_f` to use `0.0` as the default:

```
self.health.to_f >= opponent.health.to_f
#Compares 0.0 >= 0.0 if the attributes are nil
```